# Where to get gwt-maven-plugin 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: gwt-maven-plugin

The [`gwt-maven-plugin` documentation](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/) lists `2.8.0-SNAPSHOT` as current version, and I'd like to evaluate the upcoming 2.8.0 GWT.

While version `2.7.0` is available [directly](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/gwt-maven-plugin/2.7.0/) from the Maven Central repository, I am unable to find the correct repository from which to retrieve the snapshot. Unfortunately I have been unable to find this information on the project's homepage.

Can anybody please provide me with a working `<repository/>` and `<pluginRepository/>` configuration to use in my `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>snapshots-repo</id>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
    <id>snapshots-repo</id>
    <!--<url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots</url>-->                    
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public/</url>
    <releases>
      <enabled>false</enabled>
    </releases>
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Comment: Not sure why this isn't in the documentation. At least anywhere obvious in the documentation.